# Why doesn't classList.add work for html onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, this

I am trying to create a dynamic calendar. My first step is to add classes on to certain elements on click But, I ran into a problem along the way, classList.add(''); isnt working in the HTML. I could be doing something wrong I am not sure.

```
<ul class="days">
  <li onClick='#'>1<li>
  <li onclick="this.classList.add('active')">2</li>
  <li onClick='#'>3</li>
  <li onClick='#'>4</li>
  <li onClick='#'>5</li>
  <li onClick='#'>6</li>
  <li onClick='#'>7</li>
  <li onClick='#'>8</li>
  <li onClick='#'>9</li>
  <li onClick='#'><span class="active">10</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
  /* Highlight the "current" day */
   .days li .active {
      padding: 5px;
      background: #1abc9c;
      color: white 
   }
```

I am trying to apply the onclick event to the number 2. But classList.add(''); isnt working. I'm sure theres a reason... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works for me. How are you testing to check if the class is added or not?

Comment: @MaheerAli I have alot more of the html, this is just a small snippet of it. I am using my browser to check the onClick function, if it added the class then the background color should change

Comment: @MaheerAli I'll add the CSS

Comment: It seems to be working fine, though there are some html syntax errors. 1: you are not closing the first `li`. 2: you are using lower case `onclick` for the second `li`. It would also be easier to test it if you had used a snippet instead of plain code section.

Comment: Class should add. may be your css not applying.

Comment: You are using `this.classList.add('active')` then check, if there is addition of class `active` ti `<li>` on click event

Comment: @nickzoum yep I did see these problems but dont seem to be fixing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because of your CSS rule or your DOM.

`.days li .active` applies the style on a child node of `<li>` with the class `active`, but using `this.classList.add('active')`, you add the class `active` on the `<li>` tag and the CSS rule should be `.days li.active`.

Comment: thankyou. This was a perfect fix! Cheers! I will accept your answer as soon as I can

Comment: @DatBoiTrump Glad it helped ;) CSS can be tricky, one space can be troublesome!

Answer (score 1):

Your css selector is wrong, you need to remove the space between `li` and `.active`

like

```
.days li.active {
  padding: 5px;
  background: '#1abc9c';
  color: white 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html is wrong for the first li element.

Second I think that maybe you are being misled by your css selector, since the 10th li element has a span inside whilst the 2nd doesn't.
Check out this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/h6w7kaoy/1/

HTML:

```
 <ul class="days">
      <li onClick='#'>1</li>
      <li onClick="this.classList.add('active')">2</li>
      <li onClick='#'>3</li>
      <li onClick='#'>4</li>
      <li onClick='#'>5</li>
      <li onClick='#'>6</li>
      <li onClick='#'>7</li>
      <li onClick='#'>8</li>
      <li onClick='#'>9</li>
      <li onClick='#'><span class="active">10</span></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
li.active, li span.active {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you try to remove `li.active` from the css selector, you will see that clicking on the `li` element will not affect the visuals (but the class is still being added ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `classList` the problem is the selector. `.days li .active` will select all the elements with class `active` which are inside `<li>` and `li` is inside element with class `.days`. There shouldn't be any space b/w `li` and `.active`

```
.days li.active
```